# Why and when use breeze over server side ORM

Tags: orm, breeze

I was shown a breeze.js recently, its a client side library for data manipulation as we all know. The thing that I'm missing is the answer for the question in topic **why and when** should I prefer breeze over ie. pure entity framework.

The only nice feature that I know is a support for offline data. But is there anything else, that should catch my attention when developing regular web applications or SPA?

Is there a use case that after given to me I will respond with: *sure, we will use breeze there its a perfect fit.*

I have search SO and breeze faq for answer and didn't found any.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that your server-side ORM is on the server, so it doesn't know what the user wants to do with the entities (adds, changes, and deletes) until the client tells it somehow.  Breeze is the somehow.

The alternative is to have the user's every action communicated to the server, and have a stateful server that keeps track of everything the user does, so that it can eventually be committed or rolled back when the user decides.

In practice, the real alternative is usually to not let the user change more than one entity at a time in a web app, because it's too hard to manage complex data relationships without Breeze.

Breeze is easiest to use when you *have* a server-side ORM.  With the server, Breeze communicates information about entities, not DB tables, so the server-side ORM still has the job of converting entity operations into DB operations.

Comment: Thanks. That also gives me an idea, that breeze can be used when a backend enables data manipulation by third party. Cant really image the business scenario for that. But the use case would be a good example there.